# Why this XPathSelectElements() returns false?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xelement

Consider the snippet below:

```
var xpath = "//i[@a='1']";
var item = new XElement("i",
    new XAttribute("a", "1"),
    new XAttribute("b", "2"),
    new XAttribute("c", "3"));

Console.WriteLine(item); // <i a="1" b="2" c="3" />
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", xpath, item.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Any());
```

I was expecting the `.Any()` result to be `true`, but I keep getting `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your *root* element.

You can also test it with this xml

```
var item = new XDocument(new XElement("i",
                new XAttribute("a", "1"),
                new XAttribute("b", "2"),
                new XAttribute("c", "3")));
```

This will return *TRUE*

Comment: `i[@a='1'] = False`

Comment: Trying to match the _root item_ should make no difference for the `//` axis.

Comment: give the snippet a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `self::i[@a='1']` or adding that `XElement` into a `XDocument` did the trick.